# Why does Code Analysis flag me when using the null conditional operator with Dispose()?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that implements `IDisposable`. I changed my Dispose() method from this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (AccountCreateResetEvent != null)
    {
        AccountCreateResetEvent.Dispose();
        AccountCreateResetEvent = null;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    AccountCreateResetEvent?.Dispose();
    AccountCreateResetEvent = null;
}
```

Now I get the following error when running Code Analysis:

> 'Adapter' contains field 'Adapter.AccountCreateResetEvent' that is of IDisposable type: 'AutoResetEvent'. Change the Dispose method on 'Adapter' to call Dispose or Close on this field.

Is this a quirk of Code Analysis or am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: Simple full class declaration that reproduces the problem

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace IDisposableProblem1
{
    public sealed class Account : IDisposable
    {
        private AutoResetEvent AccountResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AccountResetEvent?.Dispose();
            AccountResetEvent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party analyzer extensions installed, or any analyzer NuGet packages installed in the project?

Comment: @mason, no, I'm only using the built in Code Analysis tool in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Click the "New Issue" button on [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Comment: can you share full code then only we can understand whats going on.

Comment: @PankajGupta, added a simple class that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Just a guess: `AccountResetEvent?.Dispose();` equivalent to `var tempVariable=AccountResetEvent; if(tempVariable!=null){tempVariable.Dispose()}`, so you calling `Dispose` on `tempVariable` but not on `AccountResetEvent`, and that confuse Code Analysis tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CA2213 warning when using ?. (null-conditional Operator) to call Dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229230/ca2213-warning-when-using-null-conditional-operator-to-call-dispose)