# CA2213 warning when using ?. (null-conditional Operator) to call Dispose

Tags: c#, code-analysis, idisposable

I'm implementing `IDisposable`, and in my `Dispose()` method when calling `Dispose()` on other managed resources I'm using the `?.` operator like so:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            _ChangeLock?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I'm still getting the following [code analysis error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182328.aspx):

> CA2213: 'MyClass' contains field 'MyClass._ChangeLock' that is of IDisposable type: 'ReaderWriterLockSlim'. Change the Dispose method on 'MyClass' to call Dispose or Close on this field.

If I change to a standard null check, the code analysis warning goes away:

```
if(_ChangeLock != null)
    _ChangeLock.Dispose();
```

Is there something wrong with using the null-conditional operator the way I am, or is this code analysis rule outdated, or what?

Comment: It's the CA rule that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/291) with FxCop.

It appears they have [decided not to fix it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/695):

> We decided to cut [CA2213] because it is very hard to get it right without deeper analysis, tracking variables and possibly having annotations. The current implementation is very noisy and has a lot of false positives and the value of the rule is not worth all the noise it generates.

Comment: That is a shame though, as I find the rule to be useful for a lot of cases.  Seems like overkill when there's a pretty simple workaround or it can just be suppressed by the user.

Comment: This issue has been fixed on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, the recommended source code analyzer. See the issue again.